# Configure Grub Update to Install on Partition

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I have a Windows 7 & Ubuntu dual boot system. I just installed automatic updates to GRUB.

1. First update broke Ubuntu boot, which I fixed by installing grub to `dev/sda3` in a *chroot*.
2. Second update installed itself to MBR (`/dev/sda`), which made Bitlocker ANGRY. Thankfully I had the recovery key still available.

Is there a way to configure grub automatic updates to install on a partition? In my case, the desired installation would be

```
grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck --debug --force /dev/sda3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That configuration is stored in the debconf database on Debian based systems.

On Ubuntu 14.04 you can change it by running the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```